# Creating a dynamically-named variable in PowerShell

Tags: variables, powershell, dynamic, syntax

I'd like to create the variable `offsetX`, where `X` is some number. Right now, I use:

```
new-variable -name offset$i
```

where `$i` is an integer. However, what I really want is `offset($i-1)`. How would I change the syntax of the above statement to accomplish this?

My latest attempt was:

```
new-variable -name offset+"[int]$i-1"
```

which didn't result in an error being thrown, but still doesn't accomplish my goal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the subtraction part inside `$(...)`, which is known as a [SubExpression operator](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html).

Below is a demonstration:

```
PS > $i = 2 
PS > New-Variable -Name offset$($i - 1) -Value value
PS > $offset1
value
PS >
```